# I have a question about Python the numerical computation of letters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, eval

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':['9','','3','7','11']})
col_nm = 'num'
print(df)

  num
0   9
1    
2   3
3   7
4  11
```

If the num is greater than 5, I will convert it to 5.
But after the number 10, there is no conversion.

```
string ="np.where(num == '',num,np.where(num >= '5', '5', num))"
string = string.replace(col_nm,"df['"+col_nm+"']")
df[col_nm] = eval(string)
print(df)

  num
0   5
1    
2   3
3   5
4  11
```

Is there any way to solve the logics using data and string while keeping them intact?

Comment: I don't believe your question is clear.  What is your expected output, strings or numbers? Also, it is not very clear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need first convert `to_numeric` then use condition assign

```
df['num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['num'],errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['num'].between(5,10),'num'] = 5
df
Out[97]: 
    num
0   5.0
1   NaN
2   3.0
3   5.0
4  11.0
```

Comment: @ BEN_YO OP could also use clip. `df=df.replace(regex=r'', value=np.nan).astype(float)
    m=df.num.between(5,10)
    df.clip(m,5,axis=0)`